# What is a functional approach to perform millions of unique transformations in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have an object `Person`, this object goes through millions of unique transformations and these transformations have to be done in order, sequentially.

Traditionally, I can do this:

```
var bob = new Person()
birth(bob)
oneYearOld(bob)
middleSchool(bob)
highSchool(bob)
// ...million more transformations
```

So my questions are, how can I do it functionally (no side effects/pure function) in Scala? And if I use `val bob`, will I be creating millions of copies of bob which may lead to memory issues?

Comment: "Traditionally"? A million lines of code? Just wondering, what tradition is that exactly? 
If you are talking about purely functional transformations, chances are you won't need a million of them - since the functions are stable, you should be able to just compute the final result without all the intermediate churn. If it is not purely functional, then ... well, common sense will prevail.
By the way, the way you have written it, it doesn't really matter whether `bob` is `var` or `val`. Do you realize that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)

```
i(h(g(f(bob))))
```

One way to do this would be to drop all of your transformations into a Sequence (or Buffer or List or ..) and then apply them

```
val finalBob = functionsSeq.foldleft(bob) { case (xformBob, fn) => fn(xformBob) }
```

Function composition is for clarity of expression and elegance.  Each of the transformations will involve generating a new instance off of the (immutable) existing one: that is a primary objective of pure functional programming.

The fp approach does not save you on memory consumption / object generation.  But - as commenters noted - these objects are on the heap, short-lived, and easily managed/consumed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks, so then my next question is memory, presumably the signature of each method returns a ``Person``. If I put all transformations into a Seq, does that mean there will only be one object created through out the entire transformation?

Comment: I added some commentary to the OP: take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You could also write the function composition using `andThen` or `compose`. Eg. `birth andThen oneYearOld andThen ...` and `functionSeq.foldLeft(identity: Bob => Bob)(_ compose _)`.

Comment: The copies are very short lived and the garbage collector will be quite efficient at disposing of them

Comment: @ArchetypalPaul True - and I have added that note to the answer.